"Interrupt Handling Issues After Jumping from Bootloader to Application in APM8S007 Microcontroller
Description:
I am working with the APM8S007 microcontroller, which is an 8051-based 8-bit microcontroller, and I need to implement firmware update functionality. I have developed a bootloader that receives the firmware binary file via Tera Term and writes it to the flash memory at a location different from where the bootloader resides. The bootloader code starts at address 0x0000, and the application code starts at address 0x1000.
Problem Statement:
I can successfully jump from the bootloader to the application, and the application executes as expected. However, the interrupts are not functioning, and the ISRs (Interrupt Service Routines) are not being invoked.
Debugging Done So Far:
Validated that the binary hex file sent from Tera Term matches the data received in the UART of the bootloader.
Confirmed that the data received via UART is written correctly to the proper location in flash memory.
Verified that the jump from the bootloader to the application is successful, and the application debug logs and LEDs are functioning as expected.
Checked the interrupt configuration for UART and GPIO, ensuring it is similar to a working standalone application (without the bootloader).
Confirmed that the global interrupt is enabled.
Adjusted the interrupt vector table start address as per the reference manual.
Observations:
The application with the bootloader, starting at address 0x1000, works (LEDs and debug logs function correctly), except for the interrupts.
We observed that while the UART status register and the register storing UART data are updated correctly, and the UART data register prints the same data sent from Tera Term in the while loop, the ISR handler is not being called.

Why did you post the apparently same issue with a new question? This is not the way this site works. Instead, edit your original question to add relevant information that helps us help you.

Actually that question is closed so created new question
